# Why do I get an error when inserting rows with Net::Cassandra::Easy and Cassandra 0.5x?

Tags: perl, nosql, cassandra, thrift

When using the Perl module [Net::Cassandra::Easy](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::Cassandra::Easy) to interface with Cassandra I use the following code to read colums `col[123]` from rows `row[123]` in the column-family `Standard1`:

```
my $cassandra = Net::Cassandra::Easy->new(keyspace => 'Keyspace1', server => 'localhost');
$cassandra->connect();
my $result = $cassandra->get(['row1', 'row2', 'row3'], family => 'Standard1', byname => ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']);
```

This works as expected.

However, when trying to insert row `row1` with ..

```
$result = $cassandra->mutate(['row1'], family => 'Standard1', insertions => { "col1" => "Value to set." });
```

.. I get the error message `Can't use string ("0") as a SCALAR ref while "strict refs" in use at .../Net/GenThrift/Thrift/BinaryProtocol.pm line 376`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code works as expected under Cassandra 0.6.x, but fails under Cassandra 0.5.x.

It appears as if `Net::Cassandra::Easy` is targeting Cassandra 0.6.x only.

Upgrading to Cassandra 0.6.x solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a bug in the library:

```
sub readByte
{
    my $self  = shift;
    my $value = shift;

    my $data = $self->{trans}->readAll(1);
    my @arr = unpack('c', $data);
    $$value = $arr[0];    # <~ line 376
    return 1;
}
```

(from `Net::GenThrift::Thrift::BinaryProtocol`)

Apparently that sub is being called from somewhere in the library where `$value` is not a variable, but a constant scalar. I'd report the bug to the authors.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. The binary protocol appears to have changed between 0.5 and 0.6, where Net::Cassandra::Easy seems to be targeting 0.6 only.

Answer (score 1):

hmm, it looks more like a Perl binding bug when handling exception to me.

I believe that 0.6 fixes it for you because the interface has indeed changed, so 0.6 is not raising a thrift exception anymore, but the bug in thrift remains. I've opened a JIRA case, we'll see that thrift team says about it:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-758